# Cant use already installed MDB2

Tags: php, pear, mdb2

I installed Pear with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install php-pear
```

Now `Pear list` gives the following output:

```
Installed packages, channel pear.php.net:
=========================================
Package          Version State
Archive_Tar      1.3.7   stable
Console_Getopt   1.3.0   stable
PEAR             1.9.4   stable
Structures_Graph 1.0.4   stable
XML_Util         1.2.1   stable
```

Next I installed MDB2 with the following command: `pear install MDB2`

```
downloading MDB2-2.4.1.tgz ...
Starting to download MDB2-2.4.1.tgz (119,790 bytes)
..........................done: 119,790 bytes
install ok: channel://pear.php.net/MDB2-2.4.1
MDB2: Optional feature fbsql available (Frontbase SQL driver for MDB2)
MDB2: Optional feature ibase available (Interbase/Firebird driver for MDB2)
MDB2: Optional feature mysql available (MySQL driver for MDB2)
MDB2: Optional feature mysqli available (MySQLi driver for MDB2)
MDB2: Optional feature mssql available (MS SQL Server driver for MDB2)
MDB2: Optional feature oci8 available (Oracle driver for MDB2)
MDB2: Optional feature pgsql available (PostgreSQL driver for MDB2)
MDB2: Optional feature querysim available (Querysim driver for MDB2)
MDB2: Optional feature sqlite available (SQLite2 driver for MDB2)
MDB2: To install optional features use "pear install pear/MDB2#featurename"
```

Then I  included MDB2.php in one of my program using `require_once('MDB2.php')` , but I got these errors during runtime:

```
Warning: require_once(MDB2.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/php/php_crash/phptomysql/connect.php on line 80

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'MDB2.php' (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/php/php_crash/phptomysql/connect.php on line 80
```

It is clearly indicating that `MDB2.php is missin`g. I have not included any file name `MDB2.php` in my current directory. I am assuming it is some sort of global available anywhere.

How to solve this? I also tried this:   `sudo pear install MDB2_Driver_$mysql`

I got his message for the above command:

```
No releases available for package "pear.php.net/MDB2_Driver_"
install failed
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup the include_path properly. See [the documentation](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.checking.php).